# CakePHP 3 - Saving data multiple models one form

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, models, hierarchical

First excuse me for my english, is not my native language.

Thats the problem. Im trying to construct one form in cakephp 3 and save data into two models, saveAll() function not working.

Thats the specific case.

There are users, the users have several datas like, username, pass, email, etc..
There are to doctors, doctors are users that have another field, "doctor number"
And finally there are patients, patients are users that have illness

The relationhips are:

users-doctors -> 0-1

doctors-users -> 1-1

users-patients -> 0-1

patients-users -> 1-1

Now my code (Thats bake generated code)(Example with doctors):

**User TableModel Relationship:**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsTo('Countries', [
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Rols', [
            'foreignKey' => 'rol_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->hasOne('Doctors', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }
```

**User Validations:**

```
 public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_email', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_email')
            ->add('user_email', 'validFormat', [
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'E-mail must be valid'
            ]);

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_username', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_username');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_pass', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_pass');

        $validator
            ->add('user_birthdate', 'valid', ['rule' => 'date'])
            ->requirePresence('user_birthdate', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_birthdate');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_avatar', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_avatar');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_dni', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_dni')
            ->add('user_dni', 'validFormat',[
                'rule' => array('custom', '((([X-Z]{1})([-]?))?(\d{7,8})([-]?)([A-Z]{1}))'),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid DNI or NIE.'
            ]);

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_name');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_lastname', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_lastname');

        $validator
            ->add('user_address', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->requirePresence('user_address', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_address');

        $validator
            ->add('user_locality', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->requirePresence('user_locality', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_locality');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_postalcode', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_postalcode');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('user_phone', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('user_phone');

        $validator
            ->add('last_conection', 'valid', ['rule' => 'datetime'])
            ->allowEmpty('last_conection');

        $validator
            ->add('active', 'valid', ['rule' => 'boolean'])
            ->allowEmpty('active');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('token');

        return $validator;
    }
```

**Doctor TableModel Relationships:**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('doctors');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->hasOne('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

**Doctor view add:**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($doctor) ?>
    <fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Doctor') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_email');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_username');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_pass');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_passconfirm');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_birthdate');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_avatar');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_dni');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_name');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_lastname');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_address');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.country_id', ['options' => $countries]);
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_locality');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_postalcode');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.user_phone');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.rol_id', ['options' => $rols]);
            echo $this->Form->input('specialty');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
```

**Doctor Controller add method:**

```
public function add()
    {
        $doctor = $this->Doctors->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $doctor = $this->Doctors->patchEntity($doctor, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Doctors->save($doctor)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The doctor has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The doctor could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('doctor'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['doctor']);
    }
```

Symptoms:

- User data are not validating
- User data are not saving

**Photos:**

**User View Validation Working**
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAusX.png)

**Doctor View Validation User not working**
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAMrY.png)

Thank you to all that try to help me!

Comment: take a look ath the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data): `User` should be lower case  `echo $this->Form->input('user.user_address');`

Comment: Thats wotks fine, Thank you